# to which phrase/sentence the word "happiness" belongs to in this lyrics?

Tags: american-english, interpretation, learning

in guns and roses' since I don't have you lyrics:

" don't have plans and schemes

And I don't have hopes and dreams

I don't have anything

Since I don't have you

And I don't have fond desires

And I don't have happy hours

I don't have anything

Since I don't have you

Happiness and I guess

I never will again

When you walked out on me

In walked ol' misery

And she's been here since then

Yeah, we're ****!

I don't have love to share

And I don't have one who cares

I don't have anything

Since I don't have you"

is it:

- "Happiness and I guess I never will again" the complete sentence? or is it:
- " Since I don't have you Happiness and I guess I never will again"

if the latter is the correct options doen't it feels non-semantic the use of "and" in the sentence?

if the former is correct option doen't it feels like an incomplete sentence?

Comment: These lyrics aren't standard English, so it's impossible to say with confidence what the intent is. I can *guess* that it means something like, "*Since I don't have you, Happiness, and I guess I never will again*", where Axl Rose is directly addressing the concept of happiness as if it's a person that he doesn't have, or as if he's talking to a real person, but calling them "Happiness" because that's what that person represents to him.

Comment: @gotube I had a similar thought regarding "Since I don't have you Happiness and I guess I never will again" but I still can't explain the conjunction "and" in that sentence

Comment: The full sentence is, "*[I don't have anything since I don't have you, Happiness], and [I guess I never will again]*". Does that make more sense? The "and" joins two independent clauses together, which I have marked with [brackets].